# Consecutive Absent Calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing an issue to find out consecutive absent days before and after an offday.

For example we have 2 type of employee roster. For all common day start is Sunday.

Type 1 Roster:
Sunday - Friday working day, Saturday off day duty
this offday can be any of the weekday.

Type 2 Roster
Sunday - Thursday working day, Friday and Saturday off day

My target is I want to find out if any employee absent before and after his roster offday , should considered as absent in offdays

For example: 1 day off weekly roster

```
SUN  P
MON  P
TUE  P
WED  P
THU  A
FRI  A
SAT  Off
SUN  A
```

Result: Sat also Absent

For Example: 2 days off weekly roster

```
SUN  P
MON  P
TUE  P
WED  P
THU  A
FRI  Off
SAT  Off
SUN  A
```

Result: Fri & Sat also Absent

```
USE [TEST_DB]
GO
--MS SQL 2019
CREATE TABLE emproster(da_date datetime ,   emp_code varchar(8) ,   shift_status varchar(2) ,   workmin int ) 
Go
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES (da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-01','L0094','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-01','T0115','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-02','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-02','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-03','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-03','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-04','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-04','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-05','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-05','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-06','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-06','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-07','L0094','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-07','T0115','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-08','T0115','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-08','L0094','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-09','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-09','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-10','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-10','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-11','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-11','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-12','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-12','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-13','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-13','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-14','T0115','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-14','L0094','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-15','L0094','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-15','T0115','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-16','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-16','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-17','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-17','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-18','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-18','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-19','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-19','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-20','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-20','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-21','L0094','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-21','T0115','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-22','T0115','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-22','L0094','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-23','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-23','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-24','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-24','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-25','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-25','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-26','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-26','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-27','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-27','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-28','T0115','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-28','L0094','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-29','L0094','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-29','T0115','D',0)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-30','T0115','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-30','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-31','L0094','W',570)
INSERT INTO emproster(da_date,emp_code,shift_status,workmin) VALUES ('2022-10-31','T0115','W',570)
```

W: Workday ( normal day)
D: Dayoff ( week off)
P:Present
A: Absent

Desired output:

| Date | Day | USER INPUT | DESIRE OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07-10-2022 | W | A | A |
| 08-10-2022 | D | D | A |
| 09-10-2022 | W | A | A |
| 10-10-2022 | W | P | P |
| 11-10-2022 | W | P | P |
| 06-10-2022 | W | A | A |
| 07-10-2022 | D | D | A |
| 08-10-2022 | D | D | A |
| 09-10-2022 | W | A | A |
| 27-10-2022 | W | P | P |
| 28-10-2022 | D | D | D |
| 29-10-2022 | D | D | D |
| 30-10-2022 | W | P | P |

Comment: What are your desired results.

Comment: if there is any absent before and after dayoff, I want to change dayoff to absent.

Comment: Date Day Status USER INPUT Desired Result
07-10-2022 W A   A
08-10-2022 D D   A
09-10-2022 W A   A
10-10-2022 W P   P
11-10-2022 W P   P


06-10-2022 W A   A
07-10-2022 D D   A
08-10-2022 D D   A
09-10-2022 W A   A
   
   
27-10-2022 W P   P
28-10-2022 D D   D
29-10-2022 D D   D
30-10-2022 W P   P

Comment: Can you explain what are the meaning of the alphabet `A, P, D, W etc` under `Day`, `USER INPUT` and `DESIRE OUTPUT`

Comment: Employee Status 
A: absent, 
P: Present  
D:Dayoff 
W: Normal Working Day

Comment: can you share query you have written for trial? and does your db have values as day? like 1st Oct is Saturday etc? or any remark with date where one can find date is working day or holiday?

Comment: groups of dates by present/working days, check within each group if a D day is after&before an A day.. https://dbfiddle.uk/eLf5ehTB